# Spacing between multiple choice question in examdesign documentclass

Tags: spacing, examdesign

Is there a way to control the spacing between multiple choice questions using the `examdesign` documentclass? So far I've only been able to do it by manually adding space after the last alternative, but I'd like a more elegant way to do it. I checked the documentation but wasn't able to figure out how to modify the `question` (or `multiplechoice`) environment.

```
\documentclass{examdesign}
\class{Some exam}

\begin{document}
\begin{multiplechoice}
\begin{question}
What is the correct answer?
\choice{This is not.}
\choice[!]{This is.}
\choice{This is not.}\\[1cm]
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Some other question to check spacing.
\choice{This is not.}
\choice[!]{This is.}
\choice{This is not.}\\[1cm]
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `\@endquestionhook` command to add the space; this, however, will affect all question environments:

```
\documentclass{examdesign}

\class{Some exam}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@endquestionhook{\vspace{1cm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{multiplechoice}
\begin{question}
What is the correct answer?
\choice{This is not.}
\choice[!]{This is.}
\choice{This is not.}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Some other question to check spacing.
\choice{This is not.}
\choice[!]{This is.}
\choice{This is not.}
\end{question}
\end{multiplechoice}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Adding space for all question environments is a bonus for me.